# Redirect from non www to www and also support subdomain

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to redirect my website when user enters URL without non www, and it should be redirect with www.

Example:
abc.com to www.abc.com

And also i need to support subdomain url too.

Example:
abc.xyz.com to www.abc.xyz.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="non-www to www" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Its throwing an internal error 500.

Comment: @karthik, Have you installed URL Rewrite 2.0, If not install it first you can get it from [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: @Ahmet Kakıcı, Please mention about URL Rewrite 2.0 in your answer

Comment: @Satpal, Yeah i have already installed URL rewrite 2.0
 <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^abc.com$" />     
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.abc.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />    
        </rule>

This one is working for without subdomain not working wen using with subdomain.

Comment: @Ahmet Kakıcı, yeah working :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also catch this in global, `Applicaton_BeginRequest`:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;

    if (!url.StartsWith("www.")) {
      Response.Redirect("www." + url);
    }
```

**Edit**: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478278/asp-net-response-redirect-uses-302-instead-of-301) shows that 302 is returned by Response.Redirect.

As someone has answered there, `Response.RedirectPermament` can be used with `.NET 4.0` and this will return 301.

Weird thing is. I use `Response.Redirect` on one of my sites in `.NET 4.0` and it returns `301` just fine.

Comment: Downvoted as `Response.Redirect` doesn't do a 301 redirect so not great for search engines.

Comment: strange, this returns 301 for me

Comment: 301 is good, 302 is bad. I just checked the [documentation for response.redirect on .net 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it says it does 302. You are correct that about the `RedirectPermanent` in 4+ would do a search engine friendly 301 redirect.

Comment: yeah, can't think why Response.Redirect returns 301 for me.

Comment: Maybe you have an extension method in there somewhere?

Comment: took off the -1 as the answer points it out now

Comment: No extension just does a Response.Redirect and I have tested it and returns 301. Thanks though, will change it to Response.RedirectPermanent anyway.