# Gradually migrating Classic ASP 3.0 to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp-classic, asp.net-mvc-routing, code-migration

I'm evaluating a migration from a classic ASP 3.0 application to ASP.NET MVC. I've already migrated applications to WebForms, but have decided to try MVC for this migration for a number of reasons, including the fact the code in this application is NOT spaghetti and seems to lend itself to an MVC style layout.

One major constraint on this migration is that it has to be gradual with minimal (or preferably no) downtime, and it should be possible to continue development while the migration is in progress. This means that the classic ASP code has to run side-by-side with the ASP.NET MVC code, probably even in the same IIS application.

So, I have a couple of related questions:

1. What's the best way to prevent rerouting from affecting classic .asp files? (Ignore them, HttpHandler, special reroute rules?)
2. Are there any special non-obvious issues that people have encountered in similar scenarios/migrations?
3. Are the authentication, session and general code re-use issues that generally crop up in regular ASP to WebForms migrations any different when working with ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you weigh in on my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479284/how-to-do-an-in-place-upgrade-of-classic-asp-site-to-mvc4-while-preserving-old-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only have the answer to 1

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asp/{*pathInfo}");
```

Did I get a cookie?

Comment: This means the original asp files need to reside in their original locations. If I migrate an asp file to MVC, any file that refers to it will fail to find it. So I'm starting to think the routing rules will probably have to be more complex, but I'd prefer not to have to manage a table of "migrated" vs. "un-migrated" asp files.

Comment: Once you migrate the page, you should set a redirect. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614714/routing-classic-asp-requests-to-net-seo-redirects/1615050#1615050

Comment: I think I asked too broad a question. In any case, I can't see a better solution than gradually adding more redirection rules, until everything is migrated. I could just replace all the references to those pages, but I think that is a very error-prone approach. Thank you.

Comment: Another approach can be catching the 404 error, and making the redirect there. What works better for you. The question is good, but the problems you may encounter are surelly specific to the site you are migrating. I guess there are no general rules there.

Answer (score -4):

MVC uses .net so file extensions are .aspx.  You shouldn't have any trouble at all.

Comment: You didn't understand. I'm not trying to migrate aspx files. I'm trying to migrate asp files - ASP 3.0, that is - to MVC. You know, the kind that have been around since the mid-90's.

Comment: you said "classic asp" in your question.  It's probably me though.